# How AckReplyConsumer.ack() works in Pub/Sub by using a client library

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have small query regarding internal working of Pub/Sub's client library.

Here is sample subscriber code I copied from google documentation

```
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.AckReplyConsumer;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageReceiver;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectSubscriptionName;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class SubscribeAsyncExample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String projectId = "your-project-id";
    String subscriptionId = "your-subscription-id";

    subscribeAsyncExample(projectId, subscriptionId);
  }

  public static void subscribeAsyncExample(String projectId, String subscriptionId) {
    ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName =
        ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);

    // Instantiate an asynchronous message receiver.
    MessageReceiver receiver =
        new MessageReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
            // Handle incoming message, then ack the received message.
            System.out.println("Id: " + message.getMessageId());
            System.out.println("Data: " + message.getData().toStringUtf8());
            consumer.ack();
          }
        };

    Subscriber subscriber = null;
    try {
      subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver).build();
      // Start the subscriber.
      subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
      System.out.printf("Listening for messages on %s:\n", subscriptionName.toString());
      // Allow the subscriber to run for 30s unless an unrecoverable error occurs.
      subscriber.awaitTerminated(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException timeoutException) {
      // Shut down the subscriber after 30s. Stop receiving messages.
      subscriber.stopAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

Now lets assume I change my **MessageReceiver receiver**

```
MessageReceiver receiver =
    new MessageReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
         consumer.ack();
         // Some lengthy processing like calling Download file from GCS bucket,Calling Web service etc
      }
};
```

Based on my change I have below question

1. When does client library informs Pub Sub service that message is acknowledged ? Does it waits for completion of entire code inside **receiveMessage** or it informs immediately it see  **consumer.ack()** step ?
2. What should be best practice for handling such scenarios (i.e. Where we have to perform lots of message processing before acknowledgment) ?

I searched on google documentation [pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) but could not find correct answer for this acknowledgment confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not acknowledge a message until you have finished processing it. There is no guarantee that all of the code in `receiveMessage` will run before the ack is sent back to the server once you have called `consumer.ack()`. When you make that call, the acknowledgement is immediately a candidate to be sent back to the server asynchronously.